# Automatic backup keep failing, how can I force it to run?

Tags: backup, deja-dup

Deja Dup keep failing to backup, giving the following error message:

```
Failed to read /tmp/duplicity-rrKaLL-tempdir/mktemp-Xw6o6E-1: (<type 'exceptions.IOError'>, IOError('Not a gzipped file',), <traceback object at 0x2172368>)
```

The problem remains after deleting `~/.cache/deja-dup` and also after restarting.

Is this a known problem?  Is there a way to force the backup, other than deleting also the remote repository and starting the backup from scratch?

Comment: forcing the backup may corrupt the data, I wouldn't.....Better to find the problem or use another means of backups

Answer (score 2):

That would be the best idea. You could also make a new folder and name it "Backup 2", then go to System Preferences > Backup > Location and change it. If it works, delete the old one and rename this to "Backup", but make sure you update the settings.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by deleting a corrupt duplicity-full-signatures file from my destination storage location.

Here are the steps I performed. I tried steps 1 and 2 first, and they didn't work. But I'm listing them so you know exactly what I did.

1. Deleted the deja-dup directory from ~/.cache/ (This step may be unnecessary.)
2. Deleted the Duplicity directory from ~/.cache/ (This step may be unnecessary.)
3. Identified the signatures file in my storage location that I suspected was corrupt (it was created around the time of my last good backup.) and moved it out of the way.

   ```
   mv duplicity-full-signatures.20141101T071402Z.sigtar.gz duplicity-full-signatures.20141101T071402Z.sigtar.gz.bak
   ```
4. Ran the duplicity cleanup command against my storage location. For example:

   ```
   duplicity cleanup file:///home/mrfoo/backups/
   ```